# Angular 6 setTimeout Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers'

Tags: javascript, angular, module, settimeout

I have a problem. I want to use `setTimeout` in angular to call a function after 2 second but I get this:

> ERROR: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers'; this is my function:

```
login(user) {
  console.log(user.value);
  this.loginService.loginUser(user.value);
  // this.user = this.loginService.getUser();
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.user = this.loginService.getUser();
  }, 2000);
  if (this.user === undefined) {
     console.log('username or password incorrect');
  } else {
    console.log(this.user);
    this.navbar.connectComps(this.user);
    this.navbar.getCheck();
  }
}
```

Please tell me what should I do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I got the same error when I used setTimeout. turns out angular added the following  line without me realizing it. Once I removed it, everything started to work again.

```
// remove this import
import { setTimeout } from 'timers';
```

Comment: You are right. After removing the import { setTimeout }  problem was solved. Thank you very much .

Comment: As a side note, this line of import is using another node-js `setTimeout`. ref https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args